Prefect server :prefect.exceptions.ParameterBindError: Error binding parameters for function
i am  attempting to use prefect to manage my flow,but adding @flow will result in an error.Can methods modified by @ flow not be related to classes?
enter image description here
Can methods modified by @ flow not be related to classes?But I used to use the 2.14.16 version of Perfect and directly used @ flow without any errors

in order for us to help you need to post the error you are getting and the code that leds to this error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
